# How do you debug C code in visual studio code

Tags: c, debugging, visual-studio-code

If I am to compile my code in the terminal, I would do:

```
cc -std=c99 -Wall -Werror ....
```

If I'm to run my code in the terminal I would do:

```
./testprogram text.txt 1000 1000
```

The numbers and the text file is significant to the program.

Hopefully that gives some insight into the version of c I'm using and how to execute my program. Now: how do you debug this with visual studio code? I have installed the c/c++ extension.

Every time I try to start debug it asks me to chose between two environments:
c++ (GDB/LLDB)
c++ (windows).
My first problem is that non of those two options are just plain c, but maybe I just don't know better and there isn't much difference. Never the less, I gamble on one of the environment, usually the first one, then I'm asked to pick between:
two gcc-9 build and debug active file,
one gcc build and debug active file,
and defult configuration.
I usually pick the defult config one and that leads me to the launch.json page. I put in my program directory: "${workspaceFolder}/testprogram.c" and error.. :

Unable to start debugging. Launch options string provided by the project system is invalid. Unable to determine path to debugger. Please specify the "MIDebuggerPath" option.

Nothing I've tried so far or any googling have helped so hopefully someone with a lot of experience would be able to help out here. Thanks in advance.

Comment: suggest: download/install `gdb` for windows, then (from the command line)  compile your program, including the option: `-ggdb3`. Then (after any compile warnings/errors are corrected)  `gdb --args testprogram text.txt 1000 1000`  `br main` to set first brakepoint at function: main() then `r` to start the program running, use `n` to step over function calls.  use `s` to single step the program.  use 'p` to display variables  [dbg manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/)

Comment: @user3629249 yeah currently im just gdb, using a graphical debugger would be sweet tho, but no matter gdb is working decently for now

Comment: I don't know if `ddd` is available for windows, but it is a graphical front end that implements `gdb`